# How to change the drawer title?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new in Android and working on a App. I am trying to develop an App having drawer layout. Everything is fine but I can't change the Title of the drawer menu as marked on the screenshot.

[image: Image 1: App Home]

Here is the layout file for your convenience. I have taken assistance from this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/user_home_main_view">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_mutual_funds_icl"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="252dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Mutual Funds of ICL"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_mutual_funds_of_icl"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_mutual_funds_icl"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.384"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mutual_funds_of_icl" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_current_nav"
            android:layout_width="252dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Current NAVs"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_mutual_funds_icl" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_current_nav"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_current_nav"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.458"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_mutual_funds_of_icl"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/net_asset_value" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_fund_performance"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Fund Performance"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_current_nav" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_fund_performance"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_fund_performance"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.448"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_current_nav"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fund_performance" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_how_to_invest"
            android:layout_width="249dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="How to Invest"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_fund_performance" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_how_to_invest"
            android:layout_width="53dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_how_to_invest"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon_fund_performance"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/how_to_invest" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/user_home_button_invest_now"
            android:layout_width="214dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="141dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Invest Now"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_how_to_invest" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/user_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post how you generate the drawer?

Comment: If you generated it via Android Studio built-in template then there will be a layout file explicitly created for the header of the Drawer. In that layout you can assign an id to the text field and retrieve it in your activity. There you can set the text to whatever you want.

Comment: You can even solve this using a separate layout for Drawer https://github.com/rohitksingh/Notely/blob/master/Notely/app/src/main/res/layout/notely_list_activity.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom header layout. 
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#HeaderLayout

Comment: Thank you for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

#### More Customization

If you want more customization for Your Drawer. You can create a Layout for Drawer and include it in `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`
Like this

```
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>    

     ...........
                 <!- Drawer >

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        >
           <!--- Your custom layout >
          <include layout="@layout/custom_drawer_layout"
              android:id="@+id/filterDrawer"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="end"
           />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then you can create a Layout for `custom_drawer_layout`

> custom_drawer_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <spinner/>
     <button/>
     <whatever/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope you get the idea.
You can see a related project [here](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Notely)