# How to add items to Navigation Drawer Menu Horizontally?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[image]

The above behaves like an Android Navigation Drawer Menu but written in c++ and I'm trying to replicate it in Android using Navigation Drawer Menu I have achieved it but vertically. This is a part of an app for TV and not for the smart phones. I cannot seem to display the contents in Horizontally is this even possible ? Can someone please help! 
This is what I have manged so far;

[image]

activity_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="Icons"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width ="90dp"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft ="-40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop ="70dp"
        android:textColor ="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below ="@+id/icon"/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

NavigationAdapter.java

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] titles;
    private final int[] icon;

    public NavigationAdapter(Context context, int[] icon, String[] titles){
        super(context, R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer,titles);
        this.context=context;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer,parent,false);

        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.titles);

        imageView.setImageResource(icon[position]);
        textView.setText(titles[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mDrawerList1;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerList1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resource_bank);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        addDrawerItems();

        navOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nav_one);
        navOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {

        int [] icon = {R.drawable.xxx_my_computer,
                R.drawable.xxx_my_items,
                R.drawable.xxx_favorite,
                R.drawable.xxx_remote,
            };

        String [] name ={"Computer",
                "Items",
                "Favorite",
                "Remote",
            };

        NavigationAdapter onAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(MainActivity.this,icon,name);
        mDrawerList1.setAdapter(onAdapter);

        mDrawerList1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Resource Bank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }       
}
```

Comment: set parant `LinearLayout` `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well... I don't think it's possible due the way the Navigator deals with the menu layout. But looking at your example in C++, you can achieve this by setting the buttons in a XML layout and set it to the header of the NavigationView tag.

Comment: I'm thinking the same, the only problem is there's other stuff to go underneath those icons like directory structure etc.

Comment: In this case, you can't use a Navigation Drawer. You must create a Fragment and set yourself the Navigation Drawer behavior (being this a TV app, no need to worry about side scrolling events). Navigation Drawer is used to help the user navigate through the app's screens and was not built to show dynamic info.

Comment: Thank I'll have a go at that.

Comment: You can have a custom NavBar and achieve it. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150977/how-to-change-the-drawer-title/53151582#53151582

Comment: Thank you for your reply but your answer isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

just use bottomnavigationview and make Relative layout parent layout  and then use alignparrenttop=true in bottomnavigation view simple

or

make a linearlayout with horizontal orientation and then gave it weightsum acourding your option like if you want show 3 option thn gave it weightsum 3 and divide it in 3 option simple